# jQuery Click Event sobre Div Class no funciona

Tags: jquery

Hola estoy agregando un div y dándole estilo que quiero que responda a un click.  Mediante jQuery busca que al darle clic pueda abrir una alert o realizar una función, sin embargo no logro captar ese evento, he intentado con dos estructuras pero le doy click al div y no hace nada. ¿Que estaré haciendo mal?

```js
$('.service').on('click', function(event) {
  alert("Hiciste click");
});
```

```css
.service {
  border: 2px;
  background-color: #58ACFA;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-color: 000;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-lg-4 service'>
  <div class='ejemplo'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-xs-4'>
        <i class='fa fa-car fa-5x'></i>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-8 text-right'>
        <span> Servicio Mayor </span>
        <h2 class='font-bold'>$2400</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Saludos revisa que en tu div tienes "service" y en Jquery tienes "services"..

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, error de captura al subirlo, pero aun así no da click

Comment: de hecho funciona perfecto si das click en tu div que colocaste al dar en el boton "ejecutar" te mostrara la alerta

Comment: Gracias Diego  ;) ya vi si funciona. Saludos

Comment: Ya estuve revisando, el proyecto que estoy realizando es un 1,2,3,4 formulario de pago, para implementar los pasos estoy ejecutando la librería jquery.steps.min.js, es la base del formulario, el problema es que esta librería entra en conflicto y cosas sencillas como el caso indicado no se ejecutan, cuando la quito funciona correctamente.